# Lost connection to mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux

We're receiving the following error on every 1 hour.

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 115 "Operation now in progress"

Any clue ?

Comment: Did you do any research yourself? I see a ton of answers for this on Google search results.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set high value for `max_allowed_packet` and `interactive_timeout` variable. 
Prefarably set 16/32MB for `max_allowed_packet` and `28800` seconds (8 hours) for `interactive_timeout`

Comment: increased net_read_timeout value to 60 on mysql and also increased the timeout and maxconn values of haproxy on web-servers to access mysql master-slave server.

I can't see a single abort_connections in mysql after increasing those values. 


max_allowed_packets are already set to 64M.

Will update you if the issue occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the line "skip-external-locking" in /etc/mysql/my.conf